# Оптимизация разбра JSON в Python

Tags: python, json

> *Представленный ниже код полностью рабочий и выполняет свои задачи.
>
> Интересует возможность его оптимизации либо реализация без использования сторонних библиотек.
>
> Заранее благодарю за конструктивные предложения*

#### Код:

---

`incoming.json`

```json
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "key": "what_type_of_business_do_you_operate?", 
      "label": "What type of business do you operate?", 
      "options": [
        {
          "key": "reseller", 
          "value": "Reseller"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "logistics_company", 
          "value": "Logistics company"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "other", 
          "value": "Other"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "CUSTOM", 
      "id": "****************"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "conditional_question_1", 
      "label": "Please choose the truck brand your are interested in", 
      "options": [
        {
          "key": "volvo", 
          "value": "Volvo"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "mercedes-benz_actros", 
          "value": "Mercedes-Benz Actros"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "daf", 
          "value": "DAF"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "CUSTOM", 
      "dependent_conditional_questions": [
        {
          "name": "Please choose age of the vehicle", 
          "input_type": "inline_select", 
          "field_key": "conditional_question_2"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Quantity you want to purchase", 
          "input_type": "inline_select", 
          "field_key": "conditional_question_3"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "When do you plan to purchase", 
          "input_type": "inline_select", 
          "field_key": "conditional_question_4"
        }
      ], 
      "conditional_questions_choices": [
        {
          "value": "Volvo", 
          "customized_token": "volvo", 
          "next_question_choices": [
            {
              "value": "1-3 years", 
              "customized_token": "1-3_years", 
              "next_question_choices": [
                {
                  "value": "1", 
                  "customized_token": "1", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "2", 
                  "customized_token": "2", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "3-5", 
                  "customized_token": "3-5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "more than 5", 
                  "customized_token": "more_than_5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }, 
            {
              "value": "3-5 years", 
              "customized_token": "3-5_years", 
              "next_question_choices": [
                {
                  "value": "1", 
                  "customized_token": "1", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "2", 
                  "customized_token": "2", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "3-5", 
                  "customized_token": "3-5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "more than 5", 
                  "customized_token": "more_than_5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "value": "Mercedes-Benz Actros", 
          "customized_token": "mercedes-benz_actros", 
          "next_question_choices": [
            {
              "value": "1-3 years", 
              "customized_token": "1-3_years", 
              "next_question_choices": [
                {
                  "value": "1", 
                  "customized_token": "1", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "2", 
                  "customized_token": "2", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "3-5", 
                  "customized_token": "3-5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "more than 5", 
                  "customized_token": "more_than_5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }, 
            {
              "value": "3-5 years", 
              "customized_token": "3-5_years", 
              "next_question_choices": [
                {
                  "value": "1", 
                  "customized_token": "1", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "2", 
                  "customized_token": "2", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "3-5", 
                  "customized_token": "3-5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "more than 5", 
                  "customized_token": "more_than_5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "value": "DAF", 
          "customized_token": "daf", 
          "next_question_choices": [
            {
              "value": "3-5 years", 
              "customized_token": "3-5_years", 
              "next_question_choices": [
                {
                  "value": "1", 
                  "customized_token": "1", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "2", 
                  "customized_token": "2", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "3-5", 
                  "customized_token": "3-5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "value": "more than 5", 
                  "customized_token": "more_than_5", 
                  "next_question_choices": [
                    {
                      "value": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
                      "customized_token": "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Within 3 months", 
                      "customized_token": "within_3_months"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "This year", 
                      "customized_token": "this_year"
                    }, 
                    {
                      "value": "Next year", 
                      "customized_token": "next_year"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ], 
      "conditional_questions_group_id": "1781381718904816", 
      "id": "****************"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "company_name", 
      "label": "Company name", 
      "type": "COMPANY_NAME", 
      "id": "****************"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "full_name", 
      "label": "Full name", 
      "type": "FULL_NAME", 
      "id": "****************"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "phone_number", 
      "label": "Phone number", 
      "type": "PHONE", 
      "id": "****************"
    }, 
    {
      "key": "email", 
      "label": "Email", 
      "type": "EMAIL", 
      "id": "****************"
    }
  ], 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "name": "Resellers - Retail lead form test 220908 multiple sales people", 
  "created_time": "2022-09-08T11:32:03+0000", 
  "context_card": {
    "title": "Testing multiple sales people", 
    "content": [
      "aekejskal;fjkldsfjdklsfj"
    ], 
    "style": "PARAGRAPH_STYLE", 
    "id": "****************"
  }, 
  "id": "****************"
}
```

Обработчик:
`pip install jmespath`

```py
import jmespath as jp
import json

data: dict = json.load(
    open('incoming.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8'),
)

form_questions = dict()

for item in jp.search(
        'questions[?dependent_conditional_questions!=null]',
        data
):
    item: dict
    questions = {
        item.get('key'): {
            'label': item.get('label'),
            'type': 'CONDITIONAL'
        }
    }
    for elem in jp.search(
            'dependent_conditional_questions[*].[field_key,{label:name}]',
            item
    ):
        elem[1]['type'] = 'CONDITIONAL'
        questions.update(
            (elem,)
        )

    for i, key in enumerate(questions):
        pat = f'conditional_questions_choices' + ('[0].next_question_choices' * i) + '[*].[customized_token,value]'
        asd = questions[key]['values'] = dict(jp.search(pat, item))

    form_questions.update(
        questions
    )

for item in jp.search(
        "questions[?dependent_conditional_questions==null && type=='CUSTOM']",
        data
):
    item: dict

    form_questions.update(
        {
            item.get('key'):
                {
                    'label': item.get('label'),
                    'values': {
                        elem.get('key'): elem.get('value')
                        for elem in item.get('options', [])
                    },
                    'type': 'CUSTOM'
                }
        }
    )

for item in jp.search(
        "questions[?type=='COMPANY_NAME' || type=='PHONE' || type=='FULL_NAME' || type=='EMAIL']",
        data
):
    item: dict
    form_questions.update(
        {
            item.get('key'): {
                'label': item.get('label'),
                'type': item.get('type'),
                'values': dict()
            }
        }
    )
```

Результат:

```json
{
  "conditional_question_1": {
    "label": "Please choose the truck brand your are interested in", 
    "type": "CONDITIONAL", 
    "values": {
      "volvo": "Volvo", 
      "mercedes-benz_actros": "Mercedes-Benz Actros", 
      "daf": "DAF"
    }
  }, 
  "conditional_question_2": {
    "label": "Please choose age of the vehicle", 
    "type": "CONDITIONAL", 
    "values": {
      "1-3_years": "1-3 years", 
      "3-5_years": "3-5 years"
    }
  }, 
  "conditional_question_3": {
    "label": "Quantity you want to purchase", 
    "type": "CONDITIONAL", 
    "values": {
      "1": "1", 
      "2": "2", 
      "3-5": "3-5", 
      "more_than_5": "more than 5"
    }
  }, 
  "conditional_question_4": {
    "label": "When do you plan to purchase", 
    "type": "CONDITIONAL", 
    "values": {
      "in_upcoming_days_or_weeks": "In upcoming days or weeks", 
      "within_3_months": "Within 3 months", 
      "this_year": "This year", 
      "next_year": "Next year"
    }
  }, 
  "what_type_of_business_do_you_operate?": {
    "label": "What type of business do you operate?", 
    "values": {
      "reseller": "Reseller", 
      "logistics_company": "Logistics company", 
      "other": "Other"
    }, 
    "type": "CUSTOM"
  }, 
  "company_name": {
    "label": "Company name", 
    "type": "COMPANY_NAME", 
    "values": {}
  }, 
  "full_name": {
    "label": "Full name", 
    "type": "FULL_NAME", 
    "values": {}
  }, 
  "phone_number": {
    "label": "Phone number", 
    "type": "PHONE", 
    "values": {}
  }, 
  "email": {
    "label": "Email", 
    "type": "EMAIL", 
    "values": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием стандартных библиотек. Глядя на json и на желаемый результат заметно, что словари собираются почти единообразно, поэтому:

1. Напрашивается применение своей функции object_pairs_hook для рекурсивного декодирования json.
   Пример с OrderedDict:

```
with open("incoming.json", 'r') as file:
    ordered_dict = json.load(file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
for d in ordered_dict['questions']:
    print(d)
```

```
OrderedDict([('key', 'what_type_of_business_do_you_operate?'), ('label', 'What type of business do you operate?'), ('options', [OrderedDict([('key', 'reseller'), ('value', 'Reseller')]), OrderedDict([('key', 'logistics_company'), ('value', 'Logistics company')]), OrderedDict([('key', 'other'), ('value', 'Other')])]), ('type', 'CUSTOM'), ('id', '****************')])
OrderedDict([('key', 'conditional_question_1'), ('label', 'Please choose the truck brand your are interested in'), ('options', [OrderedDict([('key', 'volvo'), ('value', 'Volvo')]), OrderedDict([('key', 'mercedes-benz_actros'), ('value', 'Mercedes-Benz Actros')]), OrderedDict([('key', 'daf'), ('value', 'DAF')])]), ('type', 'CUSTOM'), ('dependent_conditional_questions', [OrderedDict([('name', 'Please choose age of the vehicle'), ('input_type', 'inline_select'), ('field_key', 'conditional_question_2')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'Quantity you want to purchase'), ('input_type', 'inline_select'), ('field_key', 'conditional_question_3')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'When do you plan to purchase'), ('input_type', 'inline_select'), ('field_key', 'conditional_question_4')])]), ('conditional_questions_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'Volvo'), ('customized_token', 'volvo'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1-3 years'), ('customized_token', '1-3_years'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1'), ('customized_token', '1'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '2'), ('customized_token', '2'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5'), ('customized_token', '3-5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'more than 5'), ('customized_token', 'more_than_5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5 years'), ('customized_token', '3-5_years'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1'), ('customized_token', '1'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '2'), ('customized_token', '2'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5'), ('customized_token', '3-5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'more than 5'), ('customized_token', 'more_than_5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])])])])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Mercedes-Benz Actros'), ('customized_token', 'mercedes-benz_actros'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1-3 years'), ('customized_token', '1-3_years'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1'), ('customized_token', '1'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '2'), ('customized_token', '2'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5'), ('customized_token', '3-5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'more than 5'), ('customized_token', 'more_than_5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5 years'), ('customized_token', '3-5_years'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1'), ('customized_token', '1'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '2'), ('customized_token', '2'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5'), ('customized_token', '3-5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'more than 5'), ('customized_token', 'more_than_5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])])])])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'DAF'), ('customized_token', 'daf'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '3-5 years'), ('customized_token', '3-5_years'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', '1'), ('customized_token', '1'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '2'), ('customized_token', '2'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', '3-5'), ('customized_token', '3-5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])]), OrderedDict([('value', 'more than 5'), ('customized_token', 'more_than_5'), ('next_question_choices', [OrderedDict([('value', 'In upcoming days or weeks'), ('customized_token', 'in_upcoming_days_or_weeks')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Within 3 months'), ('customized_token', 'within_3_months')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'This year'), ('customized_token', 'this_year')]), OrderedDict([('value', 'Next year'), ('customized_token', 'next_year')])])])])])])])]), ('conditional_questions_group_id', '1781381718904816'), ('id', '****************')])
OrderedDict([('key', 'company_name'), ('label', 'Company name'), ('type', 'COMPANY_NAME'), ('id', '****************')])
OrderedDict([('key', 'full_name'), ('label', 'Full name'), ('type', 'FULL_NAME'), ('id', '****************')])
OrderedDict([('key', 'phone_number'), ('label', 'Phone number'), ('type', 'PHONE'), ('id', '****************')])
OrderedDict([('key', 'email'), ('label', 'Email'), ('type', 'EMAIL'), ('id', '****************')])
```

На котором видно, что функция применилась ко всем, в том числе и вложенным словарям.

2. Похоже, что OrderedDict пригодиться,так как нам нужно удалять ключи и  собирать значения в новый словарь. Для сборки нового словаря из нужных элементов( пример без рекурсии):

```
new_dict = OrderedDict({d['key']: OrderedDict(islice(d.items(), 1, None)) for d in ordered_dict['questions']})
OrderedDict([('what_type_of_business_do_you_operate?', OrderedDict([('label', 'What type of business do you operate?'), ('options',....
```

видно, что нам нужно удалить из исходного словаря первый элемент и вставить его значение как ключ в новый словарь, а остаточный хвост (без первого элемента) - в значение. Может пойдет popitem(last = False), но в однострочнике у меня не получилось. Если запустить подобный код рекурсивно, выбирая только нужные элементы, то должен получиться нужный словарь.
Может даже так:

```
new_dict = {d['key']: OrderedDict(islice(d.items(), 1, None)) for d in ordered_dict['questions']}
{'what_type_of_business_do_you_operate?': OrderedDict([('label', 'What type of business do you operate?'), ('options'...
```

сразу получается словарь.

3. Собрать полученные словари в один.
4. Преобразовать OrderedDict в простой словарь.

Конечно это только набросок, но буду рад если он поможет вам.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `object_pairs_hook` а не `object_hook`?

Comment: Единственно, почему я выбрал object_pairs_hook - "Это помогает справиться с повторяющимися именами в загруженном JSON, иначе можно потерять данные при конвертации." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519626/understanding-object-pairs-hook-in-json-loads#:~:text=This%20is%20the%20only%20good%20answer

Comment: "Собрать полученные словари в один." ну собственно это и есть основной вопрос. Поскольку там 3 типа словарей. 1-й простой одно уровневый с типом CUSTOM. 2-й с типом CUSTOM который имеет структуру непостоянной размерности с вложенными вопросами. И третий  в принципе по сложности равный первому, тоесть не сложный. Основная проблема возникала с `conditional question` .

Comment: Если вы при удалении первого элемента, будете получать его ключ и значение, то конечно вы  не будете зависеть от различных путей вложенности. Кончаться значения, закончен парсинг.